# Java Swing - Simulate process run Selection sort

Tags: java, swing

I have a final project: 
Simulate process selection sort similar to this video:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RWET645TK88
```

But I don't know how to make the code in `jList` run like in the video. Someone advised me to user Timer! But I still don't understand what I must do! 
When I click button "Start", the array is sorted immediately, it does not run slowly like in the video.

Here is it:

[image]

and here is my code:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Administrator
 */
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    /**
     * Creates new form NewJFrame
     */
    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }
    int b[];
    Timer timer;
    int n;
    javax.swing.JLabel []a;
    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jList1 = new javax.swing.JList();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jList2 = new javax.swing.JList();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton2.setText("Create");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jList1);

        jButton1.setText("Insert Code");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton3.setText("Set min to index 0");
        jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton4.setText("Start");
        jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jList2);

        jTextField1.setText("10");

        jLabel1.setText("Amount:");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton2)
                        .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                        .addComponent(jButton3)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 69, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton4))
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane2))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 314, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(20, 20, 20))
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(62, 62, 62))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(24, 24, 24)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 254, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton2)
                    .addComponent(jButton3)
                    .addComponent(jButton4)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 44, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 217, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(74, 74, 74))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        n=Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
        b=new int[n];
        a= new javax.swing.JLabel[n];
        int x=5, y=40;
        for (int i=0; i< n; i++)
        {
            int random = (int )(Math.random()*20 + 1);
            b[i]=random;
            a[i]= new javax.swing.JLabel();
            a[i].setText(random+ "");
            a[i].setSize(20, 30);
            x=x +20;
            a[i].setBorder( BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder());
            a[i].setLocation(x, y);
 //           setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());
            add(a[i], new java.awt.GridBagConstraints());
            a[i].setVisible(true);

        }
        this.repaint();
        jButton2.setVisible(false);
    }                                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        jList1.setListData(new String [0]);
        String[] strings = { "int min, i, j,temp;", "for(i = 0; i < n-1; i++){", "   min = i;", "   for(j = i+1; j < n; j++)", "         if(a[j] < a[min])","           min = j;","    if(min != i){","       temp=a[i];","       a[i]=a[j];","       a[j]=temp;","    }","}" };
        jList1.setListData(strings);

    }                                        

    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        int min=b[0],x=0,temp1;
        for (int i=1;i<n;i++){
            if (b[i]<min) min=b[i];
        }
        for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
            if (b[i]==min) x=i;
        }
        temp1=b[x];
        b[x]=b[0];
        b[0]=temp1;
        a[x].setText(b[x]+"");
        a[0].setText(b[0]+"");
        jButton3.setVisible(false);
        DefaultListModel s=new DefaultListModel();
        s.addElement("Selection sort: - Set the smallest element in first index!");
        jList2.setModel(s);
    }                                        

    ActionListener al=new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

//    timer = new Timer(10, al);
//    timer.start();     
//    for (int k=0;k<10;k++){
//        a[k].setText(b[k]+ "");
//    }
        }
    };


    private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        int min,temp2, i, j; //min là chỉ số phần tử nhỏ nhất
             for(i = 1; i < n-1; i++)
             {
                   min = i;
                   for(j = i+1; j < n; j++){
                      if(b[j] < b[min])
                         min = j; //tìm min trong các phần tử còn lại
                   }
                       temp2=b[i];
                       b[i]=b[min];
                       b[min]=temp2;
                       a[min].setText(b[min]+"");
                       a[i].setText(b[i]+"");
                      //đổi chỗ nếu tìm thấy min
             }
        a[0].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder());
        //jButton4.addActionListener(al);

    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>
        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });

    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JList jList1;
    private javax.swing.JList jList2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just update jButton4ActionPerformed method :

```
private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            int min, temp2, i, j; //min là chỉ số phần tử nhỏ nhất
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                min = i;
                for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
                    if (b[j] < b[min]) {
                        min = j; //tìm min trong các phần tử còn lại
                    }
                }
                temp2 = b[i];
                b[i] = b[min];
                b[min] = temp2;
                a[min].setText(b[min] + "");
                a[i].setText(b[i] + "");
                a[i].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder());
                a[i].repaint();
                if (i > 0) {
                    a[i - 1].setBorder(BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder());
                    a[i - 1].repaint();
                }
                try {
                    //đổi chỗ nếu tìm thấy min
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            a[i - 1].setBorder(BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder());
            a[i - 1].repaint();
        }
    }).start();

    //jButton4.addActionListener(al);
}
```